# SBCL changes EQness of a local bound function object, even though it is not set?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, ansi-common-lisp

Given this example code (from a [Reddit /r/lisp question](https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/5k9qte/im_interested_in_lisps_theoretical_background_and/?)):

```
(defun next (pos)
  (nth (1+ pos)
       '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)))

(defvar *next* (function next))

(let ((old-next #'next)
      (previous (make-hash-table)))
  (format t "~% 1 EQ? ~a" (eq old-next *next*))
  (defun next (pos)
    (or (gethash pos previous)
        (setf (gethash pos previous) (funcall old-next pos))))
  (format t "~% 2 EQ? ~a" (eq old-next *next*)))
```

Above establishes a function `NEXT`. Inside the `LET`, we keep the old function in `OLD-NEXT`. Then we redefine the global function `NEXT` inside the `LET`.

CCL/CMUCL/GCL/ECL/CLISP/LispWorks/ABCL:

```
? (load "test.lisp")

 1 EQ? T
 2 EQ? T
```

Only SBCL (SBCL 1.3.11) has a different result:

```
* (load "test.lisp")

 1 EQ? T
 2 EQ? NIL
```

The value of the local variable `old-next` is no longer `eq` to the value of the global variable `*next*`.

Why???

Comment: Did you ask on SBCL's mailing list too?

Comment: @coredump: no, not yet

Answer (score 3):

The behavior changes whether or not variables are special:

```
(inspect
  (progn
    (defun next ())
    (let ((old #'next)
          (foo #'next))
      (declare (special foo))
      (defun next () :different)
      (list old foo))))

The object is a proper list of length 2.
0. 0: #<FUNCTION NEXT>
1. 1: #<FUNCTION NEXT {10037694EB}>
```

The first element refers to the most recent definition, while the second one, obtained from the special variable, is the old definition, as expected.
When you remove the special declaration, both references are EQ (and point to the new definition).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like SBCL is trying to be smart and optimizes the variable away.

```
(defun foobar ()
  (print :foo))

(let ((old #'foobar))
  (funcall old)
  (defun foobar ()
    (print :bar))
  (funcall old))
```

Prints

```
:FOO 
:BAR
```

But if you use `SETF` on the variable,

```
(defun foobar ()
  (print :foo))

(let ((old #'foobar))
  (funcall old)
  (setf old #'foobar)
  (defun foobar ()
    (print :bar))
  (funcall old))
```

it prints

```
:FOO 
:FOO
```